# Отступ внутри блока div (CSS)

Tags: css

Имеется блок div, где содержится основная информация сайта (текст, изображения). Мне нужно сделать отступ внутри блока. Т.е. чтобы содержимое начиналось не от самых краев блока. Использовал padding: 20px; Но это свойство лишь увеличивает блок, а не "сжимает" место для содержимого в этом блоке.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

читаем про [box-sizing](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing)

```
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, совершенно то, что мне и нужно было! Весь текст отоброжаются с отступом от края див. А был слитно с краем!

Comment: ура!!! Спасибо. Отображается так, как мне нужно)))